# Who is stronger, Yami or Fuegoleon?

Tags: black-clover

My question is simple, I want to know who is the strongest Yami or Fuegoleon and why ?

I know that Yami uses dark magic but is that enough to beat the salamandar of fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official stats, Yami is physically stronger, but Fuegoleon has better stats overall, more magic and better control of his magic, that aside counting with Salamander.

[Yami Yukehiro](https://blackclover.fandom.com/wiki/Yami_Sukehiro)

[Fuegoleon Vermillion](https://blackclover.fandom.com/wiki/Fuegoleon_Vermillion)

Answer (score 1):

Yami because the darkness will over rule the power of fire as you saw it do to light magic, even with salamander yami can wihstand strong magic attacts while Fuegoleon takes alot of damage from even the likes of that one mermaid lady.